# Factorization in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules

Is this expansion a legal step?

$12^8\mod15 = 2^8 * 2 ^ 8 * 3 ^ 8\mod15$

Comment: Yes it is. $ {} $

Comment: @user222031 I couldn't find a counter example, but neither I could find a reason why it should be legal step in general. Would you elaborate your answer a little?

Comment: Is your question about modular congruences or about the $\bmod$ used in computer science? In any event, is the question about the laws of exponents? It seems to have little to do with modulos.

Comment: with or without mod we have $12 = 2 * 2 * 3$, so $12^8 = 2^8 * 2^8 * 3^8$

Comment: @GFauxPas I'm not sure what is the difference.

Comment: It is, because equivalence modulo $n$ is a [congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation).

Comment: @Grant In computer science, $\bmod 8$ is an operator that returns a number when applied to a number. In number theory it is a relation that defines equivalence classes. If you want more clarity on the difference you should ask a separate question and people will be happy to explain it to you.

Comment: Probably you intend to ask if you can reduce each factor mod 15, compute the product, then reduce that mod 15, and obtain the same result as 12^8 mod 15. If so, then you should clarify that, since the accepted answer is not related to that.

Comment: @BillDubuque While it is not what I intended to ask, the fact that 12^8 mod 15 is not equal to 2^8 mod 15 * 2^8 mod 15 * 3^8 mod 15 is what led me to the hesitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any integer $n$,

$$(xy)^n = x^n y^n$$

Because they are *equal*, they are the same number. Anytime you see one side of the equation it can be replaced with the other, because both sides are the same object.

Since $12 = 2\cdot2\cdot3$, $12^8 = (2\cdot2\cdot3)^8 = 2^8 \cdot 3^8 \cdot 3^8$

That is, "$12$" and "$2^8 \cdot 3^8 \cdot 3^8$" are two names for *the same object*, and as such the expressions can be used interchangeably in *any* context.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but a remark is needed because the OP's notation is ambiguous. If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, say, on $\Bbb{Z}$ and $[x]$ is the class of $x \in \Bbb{Z}$, then in general it is *not* true that $[x \cdot y] = [x] \cdot [y]$ for every $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}$. This is the case for equivalence modulo $n$, though.

Comment: @A.P., the OP did not say $12^8 \bmod 8 =(2^8 \bmod 8)(3^8 \bmod 8)( 3^8 \bmod 8)$, so the question isn't about modulos at all.

Comment: That's why I say that the OP's notation is ambiguous: I have never seen the notation you mention, for which I would use $12^8 \equiv 2^8 \cdot 3^8 \cdot 3^8 \pmod{15}$ instead.

Comment: @A.P. that is the notation used for the least positive residue $\bmod 8$, in which case it is an operator rather than a relation. That is how $\bmod$ is used in computer science, and that's implied here by the use of $=$ rather than $\equiv$.

Comment: @A.P. The notion we normally use is |12^8|_15 = |2^8 * 3^8 * 3^8|_15, where _ is a prefix signalling lower index. I couldn't find a simple way to write this notation in MathJax.

Comment: @Grant Almost like you did, with `$` before and after and `{}` around $15$, i.e. `$|12^8|_{15} = |2^8 * 3^8 * 3^8|_{15}$`, which gives $|12^8|_{15} = |2^8 * 3^8 * 3^8|_{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

A short justification is simply the canonical map: $\,\begin{aligned}[t]\mathbf Z &\to\mathbf Z/15\mathbf Z\\n&\mapsto n+15\mathbf Z\end{aligned}$ is a ring homomrphism.

More generally, for any commutative ring $R$ and any ideal $I\subset R$, the canonical map:
$$\begin{align*}R &\to R/I\\x&\mapsto x+I\end{align*}$$
is a ring homomorphism.